# Error when trying to run maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>java</artifactId>
    <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>java-checks</artifactId>

  <name>SonarQube Java :: Checks</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-deprecated</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-squid</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.sslr</groupId>
      <artifactId>sslr-testing-harness</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
      <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I've been trying to run this pom.xml on eclipse, and i kept having this error of:

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 2:22.878s [INFO] Finished at: Wed May 21 10:53:12
>   CST 2014 [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/61M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project java-checks: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:java-checks:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-deprecated:jar:4.2-RC1,
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-plugin-api:jar:4.2-RC1,
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-check-api:jar:4.2-RC1,
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-colorizer:jar:4.2-RC1,
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-graph:jar:4.2-RC1,
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-squid:jar:4.2-RC1,
>   org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:java-squid:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-deprecated:jar:4.2-RC1
>   from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response
>   received after 60000 -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full
>   stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR]
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Is there anything i need to add to pom.xml?

Comment: Try the Maven build from the command line. Looks like you have an Internet connection problem; maybe proxies?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the log:

```
No response received after 60000
```

Maven is trying to download dependencies for the plugins that you are using, and it's failing because of a timeout. Check your network connection and ensure you can access the Maven central repository (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).